# Add navigation arrows to quickview page Shopify

Tags: html, css, shopify

I'm trying to add navigation arrows to my product quickview page on Shopify instead of having to drag the images up/down which I've come to realise many of my customers do not get. I will appreciate any help I can get.
I believe the code responsible from the asset is the 'sca-quick-view-template.liquid'. I'm attaching the code in the  sca-quick-view-template.liquid below

```
<div id="sca-qv-showqv" class="sca-bm" style="display: none !important;">  
 <div>
    <!--START PRODUCT-->
     <div class="quick-view-container fancyox-view-detail">
        <div id="sca-qv-left" class="sca-left">
            <div id="sca-qv-sale"  class="sca-qv-sale sca-qv-hidden">Sale</div>
            <!-- START ZOOM IMAGE-->
             <div class="sca-qv-zoom-container">
                    <div class="zoomWrapper">
                      <div id="sca-qv-zoomcontainer" class='sqa-qv-zoomcontainer'>
                              <!-- Main image  ! DON'T PUT CONTENT HERE! -->     
                      </div>
                       
                    </div>
             </div>
            <!-- END ZOOM IMAGE-->
          
            <!-- START GALLERY-->
            <div id="sca-qv-galleryid" class="sca-qv-gallery"> 
                    <!-- Collection of image ! DON'T PUT CONTENT HERE!-->
            </div>  
            <!-- END GALLERY-->
        </div>

        <!--START BUY-->
        <div id ="sca-qv-right" class="sca-right">
            <!-- -------------------------- -->
            <div id="sca-qv-title" class="name-title" >
                    <!-- Title of product ! DON'T PUT CONTENT HERE!-->
            </div>
            <!-- -------------------------- -->
            <div id ="sca-qv-price-container" class="sca-qv-price-container"  >
                    <!-- price information of product ! DON'T PUT CONTENT HERE!-->
            </div>
            <!-- -------------------------- -->
            <div id="sca-qv-des" class="sca-qv-row">
                    <!-- description of product ! DON'T PUT CONTENT HERE!-->
            </div>
            <!-- -------------------------- -->
            <div class="sca-qv-row">
                <a id="sca-qv-detail"  href="" >    View full product details → </a>
            </div>
        <!-- ----------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
            <div id='sca-qv-cartform'>
              <form id="sca-qv-add-item-form"  method="post">     
                <!-- Begin product options ! DON'T PUT CONTENT HERE!-->
                <div class="sca-qv-product-options">
                  <!-- -------------------------- -->
                  <div id="sca-qv-variant-options" class="sca-qv-optionrow">
                            <!-- variant options  of product  ! DON'T PUT CONTENT HERE!-->
                  </div>  
                  <!-- -------------------------- -->
                  <div class="sca-qv-optionrow">        
                    <label>Quantity</label>
                    <input id="sca-qv-quantity" min="1" type="number" name="quantity" value="1"  />
                  </div>
                  <!-- -------------------------- -->
                  <div class="sca-qv-optionrow">
                     <p id="sca-qv-unavailable" class="sca-sold-out sca-qv-hidden">Unavailable</p>
                     <p id="sca-qv-sold-out" class="sca-sold-out sca-qv-hidden">Sold Out</p>
                     <input type="submit" class="sca-qv-cartbtn sca-qv-hidden" value="ADD TO CART" />
                     
                  </div>
                  <!-- -------------------------- -->
                </div>
               <!-- End product options -->
            </form>
         </div>
       </div>
       <!--END BUY-->
    </div>
    <!--END PRODUCT-->
 </div>
</div>


<div id="scaqv-metadata" 
autoconfig = "yes" 
noimage = "{{ 'sca-qv-no-image.jpg' | asset_url }}" 
moneyFormat = '{{ shop.money_format }}' 
jsondata = "{{ shop.metafields.sca-np-qv.settings }}" ></div>
```

Comment: For me the navigation dropdown is opening, can you check what we you get in console, maybe javascript is not loading in your page. Any leads on what browser you are using are also suggested.

Comment: instead of having to click the next image, i want an arrow that users can press to switch to the next image instead